# Redirect a single page to http

Tags: ubuntu, https, http, apache2

I currently have this redirect in my `apache.conf` file

```
Redirect permanent "/" "https://127.0.0.1/"
```

<sub>*(Please note:: 127.0.0.1 is a placeholder)*</sub>

I would like to make sure that all directories of my site are https except the file `Word.php`.

How can this be done in the apache.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

Use the rewrite engine with a rule set like this on your HTTP site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/word.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: This will not force word.php to be HTTPS  To do that you would need an equivalent rule on the HTTPS site to redirect back to HTTP.  Be careful that you don't leak secure information in that case.